# how to determine if the subprocess launched editor is Sublime or Textedit

Tags: python, subprocess

I am launching an editor , the path of the editor is passed to function below, but I do not have a better way to get if the editor is sublime or some other text editor, we can launch `vi` or `nano` like `subprocess.call(launchEditor = [editor, fileToOpen])` but the sublime path contains `-n` and `-w` flag appended at path passed as editor which is why i get error path not found when I try to launch sublime using the method below, so is there any way I can get the application name whether it is sublime, textedit or vi or nano?

```
def launchEditor(editor):

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
        f.close()
        fileName = f.name
            # the below line is not a better solution.
        if re.search('Sublime_Text', editor):
            launchEditor = [editor.split(" ")[0], "-w", fileName]
        else:
            launchEditor = [editor, fileName]

        if subprocess.call(launchEditor) != 0:
            raise IOError("%s exited with code." % (editor.split(" ")[0]))
        msg = ''
        with open(fileName) as temp_file:
            temp_file.seek(0)
            for line in temp_file.readlines():
                msg += line

            return "".join(msg)
```

example path in case of sublime for `editor` argument
`/Applications/Sublime_Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n -w` else its `vi` or `nano` ..

Answer (score 4):

Could you please tell us some examples for "editor"?

As I don't know how the `editor` variable is filled I'm guessing that you are filling it. Then you could do something like this:

```
launchEditor("vi {0}")
launchEditor("/your/path/Sublime_Text -w {0}")
```

and then in the function you can just use

```
launchEditor = editor.format(fileName).split(" ")
```

Comment: Agree, but I think this should be a comment.

Comment: I would have written a comment if I had more than 50 reputation... "trivial" answers" are converted to comments automatically and I had hoped this was trivial enough to be converted ;)

Comment: Didn't know that. Well, now you can post comments anyway.

Comment: @RonnyLindner trivial answers are still answers. Comments are for clarification and mentioning related stuff. Posting this as an answer was the correct course of action.

Comment: at the time BoppreH wrote the comment, I had only written the first sentence (_Could you please tell us some examples for "editor"?_) - this was clearly no answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching the problem wrong. The problem isn't finding out if you're being given a certain text editor, the problem is that you're being given a path to an editor that contains flags that break your script. Detect the flags, instead.

```
if "-" in editor:
    # handle it
```

You could even strike them wholesale

```
import re
re.replace("\b-.*","",editor)
# this will fail extraordinarily if your path contains dash-beginning words
# e.g. "path/to/sublime -editor/is/sublime.exe -n -w"
```